# Transforming XML into XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to transform below Source XML into Target XML using XSLT

Source XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Ffile_Details DayOfWeek="7/1/15">
<FFILE>
  <NO_20>4410600</NO_20>
  <FILE_NM>4410600.txt</FILE_NM>
  <FILE_DESC>D1F_24x_6 L</FILE_DESC>
  <VL_LVL>N/A</VL_LVL>
</FFILE>
</Ffile_Details>
```

Target XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DFfile_Details DayOfWeek="7/1/15">
<DFFILE>
  <DNO_20>4410600</DNO_20>
  <DFILE_NM>4410600.txt</DFILE_NM>
  <DFILE_DESC>D1F_24x_6 L</DFILE_DESC>
  <DVL_LVL>24</DVLT_LVL>
  <DCL_NO>6</DCL_NO>
  <RDATE>07.01.2015</RDATE>
</DFFILE>
</DFfile_Details>
```

---

1. The `<DVL_LVL>24</VLT_LVL>` : Value 24 from `<DFILE_DESC>`. The value can be 12 or 24
2. The `<DCL_NO>6</DCL_NO>` : Value 6 from `<DFILE_DESC>`. The value can be 4 or 6
3. `<RDATE>07.01.2015</RDATE>` : Value from `<DFfile_Details DayOfWeek="7/1/15">` formatted to `DD.MM.YYYY`

My xslt/xpath doesn't serve purpose as DCL_NO and DVL_LVL is hard coded and RDATE I can't pull it from DayOfWeek or today date should be ok -

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <DFFILE>
  <DNO_20><xsl:value-of select="Ffile_Details/FFILE/NO_20" /></DNO_20>
  <DFILE_NM><xsl:value-of select="Ffile_Details/FFILE/FILE_NM" /></DFILE_NM>
  <DVL_LVL><xsl:value-of select="24" /></DVL_LVL>
  <DCL_NO><xsl:value-of select="6" /></DCL_NO>
  <RELEASE_DT><xsl:value-of select="@DayOfWeek"/></RELEASE_DT>
  <DFILE_DESC><xsl:value-of select="Ffile_Details/FFILE/FILE_DESC" /></DFILE_DESC>
</DFFILE>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could include your XSLT transformation and explain what's not working about it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please show us what you have so far. SO is not a code writing service, and you will get a better response if you provide evidence of your own work. Please see [the Help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to use XSL 2.0. To do that change second line to:

```
`<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`
```

XSL 2.0 has fuctions `replace(,,,)` with regexp and `format-date()` to help with date format.

Keep in mind your xsl transformer may have no support of xsl 2.0

Comment: Not really an answer. Changing the `version` attribute does not produce the expected output described in the question.